# Create Trigger inside stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create an trigger inside an procedure. but after some research I got to know that it is not possible. can u suggest me another way I can achieve the below actions. (I cant share exact data and queries due to some reason. please refer similar queries.)

***What I want***

I have created an temporary table containing data i need. 
eg. `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 SELECT id, col_1 FROM table1 WHERE col_1=2;`

I want to inset data in table `table2` when data is inserted in temp1, which i can achieve by creating a `TRIGGER`. but the problem is I want to give a value in `table2` which will be dynamic and will be taken from nodejs backend. so i created a `PROCEDURE` which takes parameter `neededId`. but i cant created trigger inside a procedure. is their any other way i can achieve this?

***Procedure I Created***

*here `neededId` is the foreign key I get from backend to insert*

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `DB`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `MyProcedure` (IN neededID int)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp1;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 SELECT id, col_1 FROM table1 WHERE col_1=2;

    
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS myTrigger;
    CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger AFTER INSERT ON temp1 FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT into table2("value1", "value2", neededId);
    END;
    
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `create trigger` from your nodejs backend.

Comment: why not use a transaction in backend and do the two inserts from there

Comment: I might have like 4-5k rows to insert. so my team member said it will be better we do this on database from performance perspective rather than doing it on backend.

Comment: Modern network throughput should be fast enough to handle 4-5k rows easily. You should measure the time instead of assuming it will be a problem. I know the difference is measurable, but it still may be fast enough for your purpose.

Comment: Besides that, I don't see how it's relevant if MySQL simply does not allow you to create a trigger on a temporary table. So you can't do that. You must do separate insert statements. If that's not fast enough, then either move to a faster network, or step back and reconsider your approach to the project.

Comment: yes I did find another approach. this for ur efforts. I will upload it as answer in my free time

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Statements Not Permitted in Stored Routines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routine-sql-restrictions)

> Generally, statements not permitted in SQL prepared statements are also not permitted in stored programs. ... Exceptions are SIGNAL, RESIGNAL, and GET DIAGNOSTICS, which are not permissible as prepared statements but are permitted in stored programs.

[SQL Syntax Permitted in Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html#prepared-statements-permitted)

`CREATE TRIGGER` is not listed.

---

Finally: the trigger cannot be created in stored procedure, function, prepared statement, trigger or event procedure.

Comment: I do know that i cant use trigger in procedure. Can u suggest another way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can't create a trigger for a temporary table, regardless of whether you do it in a stored procedure or not.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html says:

> The trigger becomes associated with the table named tbl_name, which must refer to a permanent table. You cannot associate a trigger with a TEMPORARY table or a view.

I assume the same is true of MariaDB. It's not clear from your question which one you use. You say MySQL at first, but you tagged the question mariadb. Be aware that these are not the same database product, and they are not necessarily compatible.

Here's a demo of the error, tested on MySQL 8.0.28:

```
mysql> create temporary table t ( i int );

mysql> create trigger t before insert on t for each row set NEW.i = 42;
ERROR 1361 (HY000): Trigger's 't' is view or temporary table
```

So in your case, you cannot use a trigger for the temporary table. You'll have to think of a different way to implement inserts to your second table.

Comment: I am using mysql for my development but my hosting provider shows mariadb where i store database. So i tagged maradb. And can u suggest me a way i can achieve above scenario. Its not compulsory for me to use temp table. Any other way can do.

Comment: You should always use the same brand and version of software in development as that which you will deploy to. You're risking using features in MySQL in development and then being surprised when you try to deploy to MariaDB and find they don't work, or don't work exactly the same.

Comment: As for your task, it's simple, and the commenter J.Salas proposed a solution a few hours ago: run two INSERT statements from your client application, one to each table.

Comment: I have added a comment with my issue with that please reffer

Comment: and abt the database. Our current hosting provider has only mariadb option. and we are using it for development purpose only. when deploying we will switch to a better Mysql server

Comment: Well it sounds like this project will be a learning experience at least.